# Upgraded Postgresql from 8.3 to 9.4, how can I see my databases

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4, postgresql-8.3

I ran an upgrade from PostgreSql 8.3 to 9.4. The old directory (8.3) is still showing the 19.5Gb of datafiles, but I cannot connect to them through either of the connections. I kept the same passwords, etc.

How can I see my databases?

Comment: what does the log file says ? try starting the postgresql and then look for ending lines in log file, also show us the config file

Comment: I hoep you did a backup before doing the upgrade.

Comment: I copied the entire directory structure, is that a back up?

Comment: I start pgAdminIII it shows the old 8.3 but it is empty

Comment: How did you do the upgrade? PostgreSQL data files are binary incompatible between major releases. You should not do just copy like MySQL. The most simple way how to do it is using pg_dumpall over old database and load to new release.

Comment: What operating system? How *exactly* did you upgrade? Explain the steps taken. If you stop 9.4 and start 8.3, do you see your data then? Or did you actually uninstall 8.3?

Comment: Running win2008 r2, was running Postgre 8.3 now 9.4. I downloaded 9.4, installed it and then tried to copy over the existing data.

Comment: 8.3 is still installed

Comment: Pavel, can you please give me a little more detail regarding pg_dumpall, do I use this to "copy" the data across?